# virtualenv on windows installs in system site packages

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I initialize my project with `virtualenv` through these steps(in Windows 7 OS):

```
$ cd myproject
$ virtualenv venv
$ venv\scripts\activate
```

and then I try to install `flask`

```
$ pip install Flask
```

but I found the `flask` isn't install in my `/venv/lib/site-packages` folder

it is still install in my `C:/Python27/lib/site-packages` folder

Is this correct? I think it should be install in the venv folder

If this is incorrect, what should I do?

Comment: What you do should work. Are you sure that you are running `pip install` in the same CMD session as you run the `activate` script?

Comment: @LennartRegebro: what's the session mean? After I run `venv\scripts\activate` I run `pip install Flask` instantly

Comment: Could you please run a `pip-freeze` and show us the results?

Comment: And what is your path? (just type "path" and see). After activating the path should start with the venv/Scripts folder.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, @ Lennart Regebro:I run command in windows `git bash`, when I type `pip-freeze` and `path`, the `git bash` show me `command not found`

Comment: okay the, just type this in: `pip freeze`. If that does not work type the same thing after you get into CMD after you've activated.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: it shows:`Warning: cannot find svn location for flask==0.11-dev-20130712
Pygments==1.6
Scrapy==0.16.5
Twisted==13.1.0
beautifulsoup4==4.1.0
colorama==0.2.5
## FIXME: could not find svn URL in dependency_links for this package:
flask==0.11-dev-20130712
httpie==0.6.0`

Comment: @hh54188: Then stop using git bash, and use CMD for everything. Star over, create a new venv, using CMD only. There's a reason as to why its called git bash, because its only supposed to be used with git.

Comment: @hh54188: Made my own answer down below. Please accept it so that people in the future can understand where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start over with CMD. Recreate your virtualenv using only CMD. Then do a `pip freeze`. Things should work now. The reason why git-bash does not work is because it has only the `PATH` for git, and nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the Scripts\pip.exe in your venv folder.

Comment: how to use it? into the `scripts` folder, and run `pip.exe` or `pip.exe install flask`?