# Virtualenv installs flask in Lib/site-packages folder

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I am learning Flask and am trying to install it using virtualenv but the pip installs the flask folder in Lib-->site-packages instead of the main venv folder.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629161/virtualenv-on-windows-installs-in-system-site-packages) has been asked before, but the answer did not work for me because the OP used GIT Bash install. I didn't (using Windows cmd):

```
C:\Users\Owner\> cd Desktop
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop> md python_projects
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop> cd python_projects
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\python_projects> md project1
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\python_projects> cd project1
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\python_projects\project1> virtualenv venv

C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\python_projects\project1\venv> cd Scripts
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\python_projects\project1\venv\Scripts> activate

(venv) C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\python_projects\project1\venv\Scripts> pip install Flask
```

This is my first time using virturalenv and installing Flask, so the mistake may be silly.

I tried starting over and creating a brand new directory, and same results. I also tried using virtualenv venv --no-site-packages.

Am I not supposed to put the file in the main venv folder instead of it's Lib -- site-packages?

Comment: Can I move the folder manually?

Comment: Packages get installed into `site-packages`. That behavior is normal. What problem are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> pip installs the flask folder in Lib-->site-packages instead of the main venv folder.

Not clear enough. I'm betting there is isn't a file name anywhere on your computer that reports its path as:

```
Lib-->site-packages
```

I don't use windows, but the whole purpose of virtualenv is to install python and all the packages you install into your virtualenv directory.  However, that does not mean the contents of your virtualenv directory won't have lots of subdirectories. pip will locate all the packages you install somewhere in the subdirectories in your virtualenv directory.

And if you've ever installed packages without using virtualenv, at some point you will discover that they get installed into a directory named:

```
.../lib/python3.x/site-packages
```

which is located deep within the directory structure of your python install.  virtualenv mimics that directory structure.

So, are you saying that pip installed the packages in:

```
/Lib/site-packages
```

or in:

```
.../your_virtual_env/Lib/site-packages
```

or, somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks. I think you've answered the question. It installed in project1/venv/Lib/site-packages

Based on online tutorials I'm using, I thought it should have instead installed in project1/.